# Swift syntax for GKMatchmaker.matchForInvite

Tags: swift, game-center, multiplayer

Does somebody know how to write Game Center invitation handling correctly? I cannot figure out the right syntax for this line:

```
GKMatchmaker.matchForInvite (Invitation:GKInvite!, completionHandler .....
```

Please help, I am stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I just came across it and thought i'd offer my two cents.

this is how i implemented that function

```
GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().matchForInvite(invite, completionHandler: { (match: GKMatch!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

   if error != nil {
      // error out
   }

   if match != nil {

      // success   
   }
 })
```